# plus operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have read that the plus operator adds its Rvalues to its Lvalues. For example, if we write `x + 1;` the plus operator finds the variable `x` in the memory and adds `1` to it.

But this operator doesn't work like that because, in the code below, it doesn't add `1` to its Lvalue (`x`).

```cpp
int x = 4;
x + 1;// now the + operator adds 1 to x variable.
std::cout << x << std::endl;// this line must print 5 but doesn't.
```

If it doesn't work like how I explained, then how *does* it work?

Comment: it does not work because you don't _assign_ the value of (x + 1) to x before you print it.

Comment: `x + 1;// now the + operator add 1 to x value not x variable`

Comment: Note that most languages that look like C++ work by using `x = x + 1` or similar.  Not sure what computer language you used in the past that changed the value of `x` by just saying `x + 1`.  The closest language probably is COBOL (`ADD 1 TO X`), but that looks nothing like C++.

Comment: Note there is `+=` operator which does what you are expecting from `+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the plus operator add it's Rvalues to it's Lvalues

This is correct. It does that, but it stores the temporary result in memory, and returns the result for you to use. This result needs to be explicitly saved, by you, to some variable that you manage.

For example, if you want to change x, you can do `x=x+1`, otherwise you can use a new variable, for example `int result = x+1`.

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) there is extensive explanation. Quoting:

> All arithmetic operators compute the result of specific arithmetic
> operation and returns its result. The arguments are not modified.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding 1 to value of x but not assigning it back to x.

Use `x=x+1` this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
x = x + 1;
```

or

```
x++;
```